# How to delete all files older than 3 days when "Argument list too long"?

Tags: linux, file-io, resource-cleanup

I've got a log file directory that has 82000 files and directories in it (about half and half).

I need to delete all the file and directories which are older than 3 days.

In a directory that has 37000 files in it, I was able to do this with:

```
find * -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
```

But with 82000 files/directories, I get the error:

> /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long

**How can I get around this error so that I can delete all files/directories that are older than 3 days?**

Comment: Have you tried `find -mtime +3 -exec rm {} +` ?

Comment: I believe running `find * -mtime +3 |xargs rm` would solve that problem.

Comment: I think the only problem is `find *`.  `find .` is better.  The shell globing with expand the `*` to a huge list of files and directories.

Comment: @artlessnoise is spot on.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

To delete all files *and* directories within the *current* directory:

```
find . -mtime +3 | xargs rm -Rf
```

Or alternatively, more in line with the OP's original command:

```
find . -mtime +3 -exec rm -Rf -- {} \;
```

Comment: -1 The problem is the star in "find *", you solved it by using "find ." instead. Xargs is misleading here.

Comment: @AleksandrLevchuk it solves OPs problem, and therefore does not deserve a downvote

Comment: Question: "find * -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;" gives Argument list too long.
Answer: Use "find . -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;"

Comment: Does this also delete folders?

Comment: @AleksandrLevchuk's second solution does not delete folders, my original solution will.

Comment: If you're comfy using Perl do to the heavy lifting for you read this http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=28914

Comment: You might want to add `--` after rm, like `find . -mtime +3 -exec rm -- {} \;`

Comment: `xargs` doesn't handle spaces in paths unless you supply `-print0` to `find` and `-0` to `xargs`.

Comment: `find . -mtime +3 -delete`

Comment: Nobody said what the `--` is for.

Comment: @A-B-B It's to prevent rm from interpreting a filename as an option argument. (if you have files that start with a dash).

Comment: To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use one of these commands:

              rm -- -foo

Answer (score 61):

Can also use:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -mtime +3 -delete
```

To not delete target directory

Comment: Best answer, much cleaner than calling rm (and probably safer). Works for subdirectories as well.

Answer (score 17):

Another solution for the original question, esp. useful if you want to remove only SOME of the older files in a folder, would be smth like this:

```
find . -name "*.sess" -mtime +100
```

and so on.. Quotes block shell wildcards, thus allowing you to "find" millions of files :)